# google fonts - font family is loaded after page, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

I'm using google fonts in html:

```
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
```

CSS:

```
    .content-box{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    min-height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

When I refresh I see my text first in sans-serif for 0.5 seconds (while loading), then it turns to Open Sans

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove `display=swap` from the href attribute and replace it with `dispay=block`. That should force the browser to wait until the font is loaded before displaying text.

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing value `display=swap` from the end of the `href` value. That setting means that your fonts will load as default first before "swapping" to the real ones. This causes the flicker you're seeing.

See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-display/#values

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove display=swap as it might be the cause of this issue.

You should also download your fonts and host them yourself so it renders faster.

Having google host it for you only makes it slower to load (could be many factors why it takes long to load, maybe its your internet, maybe because there is a lot of text on the page, maybe both.)

Which causes you to see the regular font for a couple seconds.